# Is it possible for a node in the blockchain to create a separate blockchain of it's own?

Tags: blockchain, private-blockchain

It is clear that a blockchain can be created by an organization consisting of certain authorized nodes. In a similar way is it possible for the nodes in the same chain to create a blockchain separately while it is still a part of the actual chain ?

Comment: Define 'the actual chain'

Answer (score 1):

A node process is always a part of one single chain. It's not possible to run a node process which takes part in two different chains. However, you can start two separate node processes with two different chain configuration.